# CPU utilization sometimes reaches 100% and sometimes gives different results when i perform execution same testes with JMeter

Tags: cpu-usage, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMeter(in distributed mode) for load testing. Its a React web application and mongo db database. Application server and database server are two different images.

If i put 1 user's load, application server reaches 100%. If i put 100 user's load, server reaches 100%. However, sometimes, if rerun the same test, CPU usage comes less and it fluctuates often

Irrespective of number of user, CPU sometimes reaches 100% and sometimes it gives different values for the same tests.
Please do let me know what can be the reason behind it.

I tried running it for different users.

Answer (score 0):

If you're telling us that if you open your application in browser with 1 user the CPU load on the application server machine is 100% then you need to use a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) on the backend side to see what causes that high CPU usage.

If you cannot reproduce the issue using real browser and can reproduce it with 1 user using JMeter it means that [JMeter is not configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) therefore your test doesn't make sense.

Instead of comparing CPU usage with 1 and 100 users I would recommend starting with 1 user and [gradually increasing the load](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) keeping an eye on other metrics (response time, number of requests per second, number of errors, etc.) When you reach the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and identify the first bottleneck you should identify the reason for this